# Typescript function with multiple args or object map

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a function which can be called with multiple arguments or a single object. The single object is just a container for the supported arguments.

Here is an example of my attempt:

```js
export type ExecutionArgs = {
    input: Observable<string>,
    whatever: SomeOtherType,
    foo?: string,
    bar?: number,
};

function execute(
    args: ExecutionArgs,
    ...rest: any[]
): Observable<string>;

function execute(
    input: Observable<string>,
    whatever: SomeOtherType,
    foo?: string,
    bar?: number,
): Observable<string>;

function execute(
    inputOrArgs,
    whatever,
    foo,
    bar,
) {
    // Extract arguments from object args if provided.
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return doThings(
            inputOrArgs.input,
            inputOrArgs.whatever,
            inputOrArgs.foo,
            inputOrArgs.bar,
        );
    }

    return doThings(
        inputOrArgs,
        whatever,
        foo,
        bar,
    );
}
```

When calling my function, types are detected correctly. In the lines below, I get the expected errors on `input` and `bar`.

```js
execute('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
execute({ input: 'a', whatever: 'b', foo: 'c' bar: 'd' });
```

But in my function itself, when I hover my variables or object props, typescript only detects type `any` everywhere.

How do I write my function correctly?

Comment: In the first overload of `execute`, you defined a vararg. So your `arguments.length === 1` check becomes ambiguous. BTW, I doubt whether ts is clever enough to get hint from `arguments.length`

Comment: I used to do the `...rest: any[]` to tell typescript that the first overload is compatible to the second. Suggestions for a better solution are welcome :)

Comment: Your signature should be concrete. You can move the `...rest` to your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a combination of 2 problems with TypeScript:

1. When implementing overloaded function inside the function you always deal with the most generic types, which are `any` since you do not specify them.
2. Currently `arguments` object is not typed, i.e. all arguments are `any`;

By using a union of tuples to specify your overload you can solve both issues:

```
type ExecuteArgs =
    | [Observable<string>, SomeOtherType, string?, number?]
    | [{
        input: Observable<string>,
        whatever: SomeOtherType,
        foo?: string,
        bar?: number,
    }]

function execute(
    ...args: ExecuteArgs
) {
    // Extract arguments from object args if provided.
    if (args.length === 1) {
        const [{ input, whatever, foo, bar }] = args;
        return doThings(
            input,
            whatever,
            foo,
            bar,
        );
    }
    const [input, whatever, foo, bar] = args;

    return doThings(
        input,
        whatever,
        foo,
        bar,
    );
}
```

Comment: But args shouldn't be of type `any` because I set it to `ExecutionArgs`?!

Comment: OK, I did some research an the system I want to deal with seems to be **TypeGuards**. When I compare my code to your code, the problem seems to be that TypeGuards did not work on `arguments.length`. This would explain why your code works, because you pack all Arguments in an array with a proper type and typescript understands the condition on `args.length`